# How can create toggleable divs using javascript's innerhtml function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, xml, getelementbyid

I am trying to import information from an `XML` file, and create a name which, when `clicked`, will show more information. This information will be inside a `div` with no display until the header has been clicked.

This is the idea. Doesn't work.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: "Get",
        dataType: "xml",
        url: 'service.xml',
        success: function (xml) {
            $(xml).find('Service[Name="j1979"]').find("Define").each(function () {

                var PID = $(this).attr("PID");
                var name = $(this).find("Name").text();
                var source = $(this).find("source").text();
                var doffset = $(this).find("DOffset").text();
                var type = $(this).find("Type").text();
                var length = $(this).find("Lenght").text();
                var scale = $(this).find("Scale").text();
                var noffset = $(this).find("NOffset").text();
                var units = $(this).find("Units").text();

                var moreinfo = "<div id='moreinfo'>source += '\r\n' += doffset += '\r\n' += type += '\r\n' += length += '\r\n' += scale += '\r\n' += noffset += '\r\n' += units</div>";

                document.getElementById("j1979").innerHTML += PID += " ";
                document.getElementById("j1979").innerHTML += < p onclick = "document.getElementById('moreinfo').style.display = 'inline-block'" > += "\r\n";

                document.getElementById("j1979").innerHTML += moreinfo;
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Sorry for any obvious mistakes and/or ugly code.

Comment: The xml is being imported and stored into the variables.

Comment: what exactly doesn't work? Is it the `p` element not showing or create? or the `onclick` not changing the `display` of id `moreinfo`? or is it something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the code you have, you can use '+' operator to concatenate strings.

When you need to use single quote inside string defined with single quote, you can use backslash (\) as escape character before it.

Also, you need to hide the div with class "moreinfo" initially.

As for new line, if you want each attribute in new line in moreinfo class, it can be achieved by using HTML "pre" tag or "br" tag or some other way.

So code would be:

```
var moreinfo = "<pre id='moreinfo' style='display:none'> source = " + source + "\r\n doffset = " + doffset + "\r\n type = " + type + "\r\n length = " + length + "\r\n scale = " + scale + "\r\n noffset = " + noffset + "\r\n units = " + units +"</pre>";
document.getElementById("j1979").innerHTML += '<p onclick="document.getElementById(\'moreinfo\').style.display = \'inline-block\'">\r\n' + PID + "</p>";
document.getElementById("j1979").innerHTML += moreinfo;
```

or

```
var moreinfo = "<div id='moreinfo' style='display:none'> source = " + source + "<br> doffset = " + doffset + "<br> type = " + type + "<br> length = " + length + "<br> scale = " + scale + "<br> noffset = " + noffset + "<br> units = " + units +"</div>";
document.getElementById("j1979").innerHTML += '<p onclick="document.getElementById(\'moreinfo\').style.display = \'inline-block\'">\r\n' + PID + "</p>";
document.getElementById("j1979").innerHTML += moreinfo;
```

If you want to toggle display on click, you can use ternary operator to give condition in onclick function:

```
var moreinfo = "<div id='moreinfo' style='display:none'> source = " + source + "<br> doffset = " + doffset + "<br> type = " + type + "<br> length = " + length + "<br> scale = " + scale + "<br> noffset = " + noffset + "<br> units = " + units +"</div>";
document.getElementById("j1979").innerHTML += '<p onclick="document.getElementById(\'moreinfo\').style.display == \'inline-block\' ? document.getElementById(\'moreinfo\').style.display = \'none\' : document.getElementById(\'moreinfo\').style.display = \'inline-block\'">\r\n' + PID + "</p>";
document.getElementById("j1979").innerHTML += moreinfo;
```

Comment: Is there a way to hide it when clicked again?

Comment: Last question.Is there a way to have multiple of these divs with multiple activators with simple code?

Answer (score 2):

I assume that this is what you want to achieve: [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Kyojimaru/ztv4vpnz/)

just assume that the script in the demo is inside the `success` function

first, you have some error in here

```
document.getElementById("j1979").innerHTML += < p onclick = "document.getElementById('moreinfo').style.display = 'inline-block'" > += "\r\n";
```

this will not add the `p` element to the element with id `j1979` because you write it like that, where you should be writing it like this

```
document.getElementById("j1979").innerHTML += "<p onclick=\"document.getElementById('moreinfo').style.display = 'inline-block';\" ></p>";
```

note the `quotes` at start and end, and the `closing tag`

second, there's no word or anything inside the `p` element that indicates that you could click it to show more information, so put the `PID` inside the `p` like this

```
document.getElementById("j1979").innerHTML += "<p onclick=\"document.getElementById('moreinfo').style.display = 'inline-block';\">" + PID + "</p>";
```

here's the full code with some `CSS` style to hide it before the user click on the `PID`

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    var PID = "testPID";
    var name = "Random Name";
    var source = "Google";
    var doffset = "1000";
    var type = "A-9001";
    var length = "50CM";
    var scale = "100";
    var noffset = "0";
    var units = "Some Units";

    var moreinfo = "<div id='moreinfo'>source: " + source + "</br>" + "doffset: " + doffset + "</br>" + "type: " + type + "</br>" + "length: " + length + "</br>" + "scale: " + scale + "</br>" + "noffset: " + noffset + "</br>" + "units: " + units + "</div>";

    document.getElementById("j1979").innerHTML += "<p onclick=\"document.getElementById('moreinfo').style.display = 'inline-block';\">" + PID + "</p>";

    document.getElementById("j1979").innerHTML += moreinfo;
});
```

```css
#moreinfo {
    display: none;
}
#j1979 {
    color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="j1979"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a program where I needed to toggle a div with javascript.  I found a solution with this code.

```
function toggle( selector ) {
  var nodes = document.querySelectorAll( selector ),
      node,
      styleProperty = function(a, b) {
        return window.getComputedStyle ? window.getComputedStyle(a).getPropertyValue(b) : a.currentStyle[b];
      };

  [].forEach.call(nodes, function( a, b ) {
    node = a;

    node.style.display = styleProperty(node, 'display') === 'block' ? 'none' : 'block';
  });
```

You can then call the function with:

```
toggle('.idOrClass');
```

make sure you use single quotes around the class or id name

Hope this helps! :)